# How to cluster categorical variables?

Tags: cluster-analysis, mahout

What's the most appropriate family of Machine Learning algorithms for clustering categorical data? Let's assume that we have the following dataset:

```
V1        V2        V3        V4
"v1a"     "v2b"     "v3b"     "v4c"
"v1b"     "v2f"     "v3a"     "v4c"
"v1a"     "v2e"     "v3b"     "v4c"
```

Is there any way to cluster them somehow? I am particular interested in doing so through Apache Mahout. Any hint \ idea is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The question that you need to answer *first* is:

**What is a cluster?**

Obviously, many of the existing cluster definitions (connected by steps of Euclidean distance less than epsilon) etc. will not be useful.

There are tricks to vectorize such data so that you can still run k-means on it.

But more often than not, the results will be *useless*, because people did not consider what they are doing *first*.

So first try to find out what you want to do, then look for tools to do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. May I ask you to give me a bit more hints? Which family of algorithms could work well for that problem? Just make a guess! :D What about those based on Bayes' theorem?

Comment: What does Bayes theorem mean for your data?
I don't know your data, I can't tell you what is meaningful to you.